# How to access the class itself from within a class without using its name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is it possible to access the `class` itself inside of a classes function:

```
class MyClass {
  static get myFunction() { return "foo"; }
  
  constructor() {
    console.log(MyClass.myFunction); // "foo" -- it works when using its name. This is what we want but without using the name
    console.log(this.myFunction); //undefined
    console.log(this.prototype.myFunction); //Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined
  }

}

new MyClass();
```

Is it possible to achieve the same as you do with `MyClass.myFunction()` and access the `static` methods without using the name of the class (in this case without using `MyClass` in this example?

Something like `this.master.myFunction()` (I’m just making `master` up here it’s obviously not called master)

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/hawituxosu/1/edit?js,console

Is that even possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `constructor` for this

> Returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object

The constructor property has three purposes:

**1.** Get the class object.

**2.** Create an new instance

**3.** Invoke super constructor

```
class MyClass {
  static get myFunction() { return "foo"; }

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.constructor.myFunction); 
  }

}

new MyClass();
```

Comment: It’s exactly what I was looking for! That is fabulous! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

an option you can do here is to call static method inside an instance method and call that instance method

```
class MyClass {
  static get myFunction() { return "foo"; }

  constructor() {
    console.log(MyClass.myFunction); // "foo" -- whith using its name it works. This is what we want but without using the name
    console.log(this.constructor.myFunction);
  }
  myFunction2() {
     return this.constructor.myFunction();
  }
}
const master = new MyClass();
master.myFunction2();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   this.constructor.myFoo
```

The constructor property helps you here

Answer (score 1):

You could work around getting to the class name using:

```
this.__proto__.constructor.name   // MyClass
```

```js
class MyClass {
  static get myFunction() { return "foo"; }

  constructor() {
    
    console.log(eval(this.__proto__.constructor.name + ".myFunction"));  //foo
  }

}

new MyClass();
```